# Postgis - Get all unique area from set of overlapping polygon

Tags: postgis

I have a layer with X polygons. Some of them overlaps, some of them don't :
[image: input layer]

I need to isolate each distinct area of this layer like this :

output layer

[image]

I tried with boundary and polygonize :

```
SELECT ST_Polygonize(geom) AS geom FROM (
     SELECT ST_Union(geom) AS geom FROM (
         SELECT ST_Boundary(geom) AS geom FROM buffers
     ) AS lines
) AS union_lines
```

It works pretty well but I have some missing parts :

[image: Missing parts]

If I reduce the number of input polygons, there is no missing parts.

Do you have a better solution than mine to achieve my goal ?
Thank you a lot for your time

Comment: Can you also provide the data? Preferably as WKT literals or even a shapefile.

Comment: Hi, yes of course. You can download the data here : https://framadrop.org/lufi/r/VsaVcjPduX#dBRipWJTYWWDdqZ32Rbn8tUZzToSewkGnMgOTcDFC0o=